# memory exhausted on line 2860 with (if else)

Tags: php

I've searched in various places for this solution, but have not been able to solve the problem that happened to me. What happens is actually in the following code:

> [21-Jul-2017 23:35:30 UTC] PHP Parse error:  memory exhausted in
>   /home/.../public_html/folder/index.php on line 2860

Chronologically, I want to create many options if one of the options is met. Here's the problem code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['url'])) {
$u = $_GET['url'];

if($u == 'old/page1.html') {
header('Location: /new/page1.htm');
} if($u == 'old/page2.html') {
header('Location: /new/page2.htm');
} if($u == 'old/page3.html') {
header('Location: /new/page3.htm');
} if($u == 'old/page4.html') {
header('Location: /new/page4.htm');
}
//.....
//.....(line 5691)
}
?>
```

If I only use the above code, then it can run normally. But if I use my code number of 5691 lines, then the warning starts to appear and the site can not be opened.

I suspect there is a problem on the maximum amount of memory used, but do not know exactly.

Comment: How does one end up with a 5,700-line PHP file?

Comment: I think you need to take a look at [this list](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php).

Comment: You need to do something like this https://3v4l.org/Trf8v

Comment: @Kai My url can be from database and add auto code wear `notepad plus`

Comment: @vascowhite How to implement that code for page redirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to sort it out this way, then this would probably be better:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
    $u = $_GET['url'];

    $redirects = [
        'old/page1.html' => '/new/page1.htm',
        // ...
    ];

    if (array_key_exists($u, $redirects)) {
        $redirect = $redirects[$u];

        header(sprintf(
            'Location: %s',
            $redirect
        ));
    }
}
```

This way at least you can manage the redirect mapping separately, without the need to add a bunch of conditions.

You could also put the mapping into a separate file:

```
<?php

return [
    'old/page1.html' => '/new/page1.htm',
    // ...
];
```

and then adjust your script:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
    $u = $_GET['url'];

    $redirects = require __DIR__ . '/redirects.php';

    if (array_key_exists($u, $redirects)) {
        $redirect = $redirects[$u];

        header(sprintf(
            'Location: %s',
            $redirect
        ));
    }
}
```

This way you don't need to modify your script if the mapping changes.

Alternatively, use `elseif`:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
        $u = $_GET['url'];

        if ($u == 'old/page1.html') {
            header('Location: /new/page1.htm');
        } elseif ($u == 'old/page2.html') {
            header('Location: /new/page2.htm');
        } elseif ($u == 'old/page3.html') {
            header('Location: /new/page3.htm');
        } elseif ($u == 'old/page4.html') {
            header('Location: /new/page4.htm');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes this works using elseif() whereas before I have tried with else if() but failed ...

Comment: There's no difference between `else if` and `elseif`, see http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace those 5691 lines of code with this

```
if(isset($_GET['url'])) {
$u = $_GET['url'];

if(substr($u, 3) === 'old'){
    $new = str_replace('old', 'new', $u);
    header("Location: $new");
}
```

Comment: This change takes hard work to change up to thousands of lines. After all, my url is not always the same.
Does your recommendation guarantee work up to 5691 lines? My file is 338kb

Comment: I'm not guaranteeing anything. You came here asking for help and I am suggesting a sensible alternative to your code. You could at least test it? If you give a few examples of your actual URL's then I can modify the code to suit. __This will definitely work for the example URL's you have provided.__

Comment: Just be clear, you should replace _all_ of you 5691 lines with just these 6, so select all, delete, type. 5 mins work :)

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean it that way, I was just panicking in pursuit of time